# how to set format while reading RTF files in java?

Tags: java, swing, rtf, jeditorpane

I need to read some RTF files in Java .So i got a code which worked fine initially . But my question is that  : Is it possible to set format (Eg: UTF-8 ,UTF-16,etc) while reading these files ?

Here i have posted the code which reads RTF file :

```
public static String rtf_read(String fileName) throws Exception, BadLocationException
{
JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
p.setContentType("text/rtf");
EditorKit rtfKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
rtfKit.read(new FileReader(fileName), p.getDocument(), 1);
rtfKit = null;
// convert to text
EditorKit txtKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/plain");
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
txtKit.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0, p.getDocument().getLength());
String documentText = writer.toString();
return documentText;
}
```

Comment: The codepage is part of RTF file

Comment: A standard RTF file can only consist of 7-bit ASCII characters. Except if they contain binary data, e.g. for images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `FileReader` is using the default encoding. Fortunately, the `read()` method was overloaded to handle streams as well - and for them, you can set the encoding you want to use:

```
rtfKit.read(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me with the following lines of code:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(rtfFilePath);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
rtfKit.read(buffReader, p.getDocument(), 0);
```